# Multiple Commas

Tags: commas

In the following sentence, does there need to be a comma before so? Or is the comma after it enough?

> I don’t understand what the word means, so, of course, I look it up in the dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I believe this covers comma usage discussed at length in several English Language Learners site questions

Answer (score 1):

Commas are mostly a matter of style. *The Chicago Manual of Style* prescribes a comma before *so* when it functions as a coordinating conjunction. The comma after that *so* — to delimit an adverbial phrase — is optional, and its omission generally makes for less comma fussiness:

> *I don’t understand what the word means, so of course, I look it up in the dictionary.*

What you have here is a coordinating conjunction (*so*), an adverbial phrase (*of course*) and two independent clauses (*I don’t understand what the word means* and *I look it up in the dictionary*) . . .

From *The Chicago Manual of Style* (see in **bold**):

> 6.32: Commas with a participial or adverbial phrase plus a conjunction
>
> When a participial or adverbial phrase immediately follows a
> coordinating conjunction, the use of commas depends on whether the
> conjunction joins two independent sentences. If the conjunction is
> simply a part of the predicate or joins a compound predicate, the
> first comma follows the conjunction (see also 6.23).
>
> *We were extremely tired and, in light of our binge the night
> before, anxious to go home.*
>        *The Packers trailed at halftime
> but, buoyed by Rodgers’s arm, stormed back to win.*
>
> **If the conjunction joins two independent clauses, however, the comma
> precedes the conjunction** (see also 6.22).
>
> *We were elated, but realizing that the day was almost over, we
> decided to go to bed.*
>
> Strictly speaking, it would not be wrong to add a second comma after
> but in the last example. Such usage, which would extend the logic of
> commas in pairs (see 6.17), may be preferred in certain cases for
> emphasis or clarity. See also 6.26.